# What is Clearcase Doctor and Why we need it?

Tags: clearcase

I am learning ClearCase and just going through the installation folder and under below location I found it:

- Start > Programs > IBM Rational > IBM Rational ClearCase >
  Administration > ClearCase Doctor

So please instruct for what purpose we use CleaseCase Doctor.

Answer (score 1):

ClearCase Doctor is a tool used for diagnostic purpose, analyzing the various elements which could prevent ClearCase to run properly.

Those elements are mainly network issues, as well as services (which must run)

There is an option to prevent ccdoctor to run at logon, if you do not want to see it *every* time.

See "[ClearCase Doctor](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/ccdoctor/default_topic.htm)":

> ClearCase®Doctor analyzes and reports on this computer's readiness to run ClearCase or ClearCase LT. You can also use it for either of the following tasks:
>
> - analyze this computer's ability to contact specific ClearCase servers on your local area network
> - analyze another Windows computer on your local area network

Comment: OK, So it just a tool which tells us about the configuration and network connection of CC, but we can't do any operation with this.

Comment: @R.Sha yes, you can only launch it on demand to see if everything looks fine.

Comment: @R.Sha don't forget to revisit your older questions, in light of http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.